# $T+i\operatorname{Id}$ is an isomorphism for self-adjoint $T$

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T:H\to H$ be a self-adjoint continuous operator on a complex Hilbert space.

> **Claim:** $T+i\operatorname{Id}$ is an isomorphism and $\|(T+i\operatorname{Id})^{-1}\|\leq 1$.

A few observations:

(1) To show that $T+i\operatorname{Id}$ is an isomorphism, it will be enough to show that the operator is bijective.

(2) For each $n$, the operator $T^{2^n}$ is also bounded, and $\|T^{2^n}\|=\|T\|^{2^n}<\infty$.

(3) $T+i\operatorname{Id}=i(\operatorname{Id}-iT)$ which is invertible when $\|iT\|=\|T\|<1$ by the von Neumann series.

(4) $\|(T+i\operatorname{Id})x\|^2=\|Tx\|^2+\|x\|^2$ and therefore $T+i\operatorname{Id}$ has trivial kernel.

I don't know how relevant those are for a solution, but that's what I thought about so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this is clear from the Spectral Theorem...

Item (4) says not only that $T+i$ has trivial kernel but that it's bounded below; hence $R=(T+i)(H)$ is closed. So it's enough to show that $R$ is dense. So you need only show that $R^\perp=0$. But if $\langle(T+i)x,y\rangle=0$ for all $x$ then $\langle x,(T-i)y\rangle=0$ for all $x$, hence, since $T-i$ also has trivial kernel, $y=0$.

Comment: Thank you, good answer. Could you tell me which version of the Spectral Theorem you are referring to?

Comment: @JohnSteinbeck The Spectral Theorem for bounded normal operators on a Hilbert space... That can be phrased in various ways - I like the one that says $T$ is unitarily equivalent to the map $f\mapsto mf$ on $L^2$ of some measure space, for some bounded function $m$. Now $T$ self-adjoint says the multiplier $m$ for $T$ is real, and clearly multiplication by $m+i$ is then an isomorphism...

Comment: That's really smart. Could the Spectral Thm for bounded normal operators on a Hilbert space also be phrased as: $T$ is unitarily equivalent to the map $x\mapsto mx$ on $\ell^2$ for some $m\in \ell^\infty$?

Comment: @JohnSteinbeck No. That would imply that there was a basis for $H$ consisting of eigenvectors for $T$. Evidently you don't know the theorem - it's not the sort of thing we're going to be able to cover in comments here, you might study up on it some time. Heh, note of course that for a problem like yours using the Spectral Theorem is more or less regarded as cheating, since it makes things too easy. And also since it's so much deeper than the result you wanted to prove...